# Inkscape XML y-axis is not what it should be

Tags: inkscape

I open IS.

I note the (0,0) point in the lower left-hand corner of the viewBox.

I create a rectangle width=300px, height=300px and set it in the viewBox close to the lower left-hand corner.

I close and save the file.

I open the file in a hex editor. Below is the group for the rectangle after manually editing the x & y = (100,100)

---

```
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:#8400ff;fill-opacity:0.27167634;stroke:#ff80e5;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4190"
       width="300"
       height="300"
       x="100"
       y="100" />
  </g>
```

---

After re-opening the file in IS the box appears to be (100,100) from the TOP left-hand, not the BOTTOM left-hand as the rulers & the X: Y: in the applications status bar lower right-hand would have me think I should be able to read the XML.

How can I rely on and translate the what I see in the application window with what I read in the XML?

Answer (score 1):

SVG coordinates are computer coordinates, with Y pointing down from the top. Inkscape shows Y pointing up in the style of classical graphic design.

There is some reference [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Coordinates.html), and a related question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61708/inkscape-why-do-coordinates-in-gui-and-xml-differ).